# What collation should be used for french language?

Tags: mysql, collation

I developed a website in french language, and I am facing disorder in the french words for the country list. Can any one let me know what collation type should be used for french language for language's table?

Link : http://www.atlasanesp.mr/register.php
Please look at the dropdown with the title 'Pays de résidence'

Comment: UTF8-bin should work.

Comment: @Rajlaksh i have changed the collation from utf8_general_ci to utf8_bin but i didn't work ... please check the link
http://www.atlasanesp.mr/register.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use UTF-8.

Add in the top of the HTML page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and in the PHP page:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in your DB launch the query:

```
mysqli_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

it should work!

Comment: Note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from the language soon.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question sufficiently. @haisum-usman is asking about the collation (i.e. the proper sorting), not the charset.

Answer (score 4):

Just always use UTF-8, for any language. But it's important to make sure your code is also in UTF-8. Check your PHP files and all other text files in the project.

UTF-8 is considered standard today. It's common newbie error to not use it, happens to people that speak non English language.

In MySQL it would be utf8_general_ci if you need your searches to be not case sensitive.

Comment: If we're talking about MySQL I'd recommend `utf8_general_ci` to be a little more precise.

Comment: @Anticom `utf8_general_ci` is pretty much broken, use `utf8_unicode_ci` instead

Comment: @PeeHaa Got any reference? I'm interested in what's broken in `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: @rikpg nothing changes,all same. I have defined the same characterset and content type which is placed below,

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

And the table's collation is 'utf8_general_ci'.
Please have a look at http://www.atlasanesp.mr/register.php
title 'Pays de résidence'

Answer (score 3):

After a long  RND i found two things that needs to be used to handle different languages along with their special characters.

1- You need to define the collation of your table to be utf8_general_ci.

2- You need to define the  '**mysql_set_charset('utf8');**' in the file where you made connection with the database and right after the selection of database like '**mysql_select_db**' use this 'mysql_set_charset' this will allow you to add and retrieve data properly in what ever the language it is.

**I personally appreciate the answers given by my fellows and thanks to all.**